# How to configure the url with a combination of url segmentation and querystring for web api rest url

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

(using Web api 1.0)
I have a scenario where my action has multiple parameters like
GetCustomer(int id, string email)
where the url would be specified as

GET
api/Customer/{id}/{email}

But i am looking to configured the url as

api/Customer/{id}?email={email}

So it's a combination if url segmentation with query string. Currently when i am trying to set this i am getting this below error.

**The route URL cannot start with a '/' or '~' character and it cannot contain a '?' character.
Parameter name: routeUrl**

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
         "Help Area",
         "",
         new { controller = "Help", action = "Index" }
     ).DataTokens = new RouteValueDictionary(new { area = "HelpPage" });

    }
}

public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {                                                                             

      config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
          name: "DefaultApi",
          routeTemplate: "{controller}/{id}",
          defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
      );

      config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
           name: "ApiWithAction",
           routeTemplate: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
           defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
       ); 
    }
}
```

kindly help me in fixing this thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try something with Route attribute?

Comment: Show how you configure the route.

Comment: @FelipeOriani i have just updated my route config in the questions, plz let me know if you need more info thanks for help

Comment: @Nkosi i have just updated my route config in the questions, plz let me know if you need more info thanks for help

Comment: You say web api but the routes you are showing are for MVC not web api. So it's not clear what you are referring to

Comment: @Nkosi please find the web api config updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your configuration needs updating

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config) {

      config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
          name: "CustomerApi_GetCustomer",
          routeTemplate: "api/Customer/{id}",
          defaults: new { controller = "Customer" action = "GetCustomer" }
      );

      config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
          name: "DefaultApi",
          routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
          defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
      );

      config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
           name: "ApiWithAction",
           routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
           defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
       ); 
    }
}
```

If you make a request to `api/Customer/{id}?email={email}`

the binder will automatically match the `GetCustomer(int id, string email)` with the `email` parameter from the url

Comment: i see that after placing your code   api/Customer?id={id}&email={email} is working but not api/Customer/{id}?email={email} throwing No action was found on the controller 'api' that matches the request.

Comment: did you put it in the order i showed? because order matters when setting up routes.

Comment: yes i have given the exact order but i get the error                        "No action was found on the controller 'api' that matches the request."

Comment: That looks like your web api config is not being called. Where do you call `WebApiConfig.Register`. Check in the startup. Also check your controller and make sure it inherits from `ApiController` and not `Controller`

Comment: WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);  is called from Global.ascx and it is  working for sure

Comment: Ok cool so we can rule that out. Check your controller and make sure it is inheriting from the correct class

Comment: thanks for the help , Seems that my bad i had to have the param as {id} not anything other than that . Now with change in that it started working.  But just a quick questions is this format valid in web api and is it allowed?    api/v1/customer/{id}/active?from_date={date}&end_date={date}   as this is what is expected

Comment: Hey i could get this api/v1/customer/{id}/active?from_date={date}&end_date={date}  working as well  Thanks a Ton man you saved my day. Have a great day ahead

Comment: Glad to help. Yes everything you mentioned in your previous comments are allowed. You just need to configure your routes and your set. Happy coding!!!